# Java parsing XML date - exclude time

Tags: java, parsing

This is the first time I am working this intensly with XML in Java. The code uses JAXB to generate classes and then parse. I have an XML with a date...

A class was generated by JAXB from my XML. It generated the following for the field:

```
@XmlElement(name = "CoverStartDate", required = true)
protected XMLGregorianCalendar coverStartDate;
```

In my logic I have the following

```
xxxx.setCoverStartDate(xmlGregorianCalendar(theDate)
```

There is a method xmlGregorianCalendar which looks something like this:

```
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
gregorianCalendar.setTime(date);
return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
```

My return XML that is generated, had the date with a time specified. I only want the date (year-month-day).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendarDate%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) instead of simply using any of the `DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(...)` methods.

I don't know what is `theDate` in your code snippet, however if you're working with [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects you can use the following.

```
  public static XMLGregorianCalendar setCoverStartDate(Date date) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTime(date.getTime());
    return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(
        calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
        getTimeZone(calendar));
  }

  public static int getTimeZone(Calendar calendar) {
    return (int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  }
```

(Note that `calendar's` `Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET` is in milliseconds and the `newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(...)` method expects the timezone value in minutes, thus it needs to be converted.)

(Also note that `Calendar's` month index is 0-based, while `XMLGregorianCalendar's` month is 1-based.)

If this isn't working then the XML schema you've used to generate your JAXB classes is probably erroneous: maybe it does not specify the usage of the `xs:date` XML schema type (probably it uses `xs:dateTime` instead).

Only one last advice: create your JAXB classes by hand. Then you can specify annotations like [`@XmlSchemaType`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchemaType.html) on your classes' fields giving you much more control.

Comment: +1 for `@XmlSchemaType` for more information on how it can be used with date/time properties see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/01/jaxb-and-datetime-properties.html

Comment: This was great. I implemented it and it is looking a lot better. Now instead of my XML looking like this:  <CoverStartDate>2011-01-01T00:00:00.000+02:00</CoverStartDate>.  It looks like this: <CoverStartDate>2011-01-01+02:00</CoverStartDate>. Is there anything more I can do to get rid of the timezone too...so it only displays the date portion?

Comment: Okay...sorry I figured it out. I used DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED as the timezone setting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a DateFormatter that formats it into only the DATE part, ignoring the time.

Something like: `(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMMM dd")).format(theDate));`

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage a JAXB external binding file to so that a `GregorianCalendar` is generated into your object model.  This will eliminate the need for you to do the conversion.  An example of doing something similar can be found here:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/xml-schema-to-java-generating.html

The `javax.xml.bing.DatatypeConverter` class can be useful in creating the necessary `XmlAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

Date fechaBajaPrevista = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

XMLGregorianCalendar calendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(
                        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(fechaBajaPrevista));
```