# WSDL2Java code generation and date/dateTime fields

Tags: date, apache-axis, wsdl2java

Given the following xsd fragment:

```
<simpleType name="ConsentDateType">
    <restriction base="date">
        <minInclusive value="2000-01-01Z" />
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

I find that WSDL2Java (1.6.2) is producing XMLGregorianCalendar instances to hold the dates. By itself this is not a problem, but when the fields are serialized to XML the time is included as well. And this is indeed a problem, since the XML is used in a SOAP request, which is rejected because a field containing both a date and a time does not follow the formal xsd:date requirements (only a date and a timezone offset is allowed).

What can I do to get around this problem?

-Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[Java parsing XML date - exclude time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736148/java-parsing-xml-date-exclude-time)

Solution is to create XMLGregorianCalendarDate objects. They will be serialized correctly.

-Michael